# Irreversible migrations in Alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Not all database migrations are reversible. When using Alembic+SQLAlchemy, is there a (canonical) way to "mark" my `downgrade` function/migration so that it cannot be reversed?

Compare [ActiveRecord migrations where you can raise `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods) from your `down` method to signal this.

Would raising an exception (any exception) in `donwgrade` cause the downgrade to fail "cleanly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exception is enough. It will fail the migration and you will never be able to go back.

```
def downgrade():
    raise Exception("Irreversible migration")
```